# WPF double letter keybinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, shortcut

I'm trying to recreate the same double letter key combo shortcut Visual Studio are using in WPF, where you use Alt+V+A to change view.
I have tried different combinations of the code below.

```xml
<KeyBinding Key="V,A" Command="{Binding Path=ShowViewCommand}" CommandParameter="ArtifactView" Gesture="Alt+" />
```

Comment: Fix incorrect indentation + color the code accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a SO post says you can do this with a comma delimited list, but it didn't work for me.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="V,A" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I think the commands you're seeing in visual studio are relying on the menu structure shortcuts.

Like with notepad you can do Alt+F for file menu then S for save or X for exit. 
You could define a menu and sub menu.
Make the command for the parent Alt+V using the _ before the letter V in the menu header or using an explicit inputgesture will invoke it. Which will "open" the menu if it's just a parent menu with no command.

Then a sub menu item within SomeVing with Alt+A similarly.

Or

You could try this approach here: https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/multikeygesture  Which inherits from keygesture.